# javascript functions only working once

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have these two javascript functions that change a background and show and hide fields, however it only works once for each button

```
function showabout(){


        hidecontact = document.getElementById("contactus");

        hidecontact.style.display = "none";


        hide.style.backgroundImage = "url(aboutus.jpg)";


        showabout = document.getElementById("aboutus");
        showabout.style.display = "inline";
        showabout.style.cssFloat = "left";
        secbuttons.style.paddingLeft = "670px";




        }

        function showcontact(){


        hideabout = document.getElementById("aboutus");
        hideabout.style.display = "none";   


        hide.style.backgroundImage = "url(contact.jpg)";


        showcontact = document.getElementById("contactus");
        showcontact.style.display = "inline";
        showcontact.style.cssFloat = "left";
        secbuttons.style.paddingLeft = "670px";




        }


   <font color="#33FF66"><h2 style="cursor:pointer" onmouseover = "showabout()">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</h2></font>

<font color="#33FF66"><h2 style="cursor:pointer" onclick="showcontact()">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</h2></font><br />

<font color="#33FF66"><h2 style="cursor:pointer" onmouseover = "showcontact()">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</h2></font>
```

The three H2s are the lines causing the errors. It says "uncaught type error, object is not a function".

Comment: Can you provide sample HTML code. B,coz I think that there is a n issue of ID , or maybe your browser does not support it completely.

Comment: added html code, I've tried numerous browsers and get the same error.

Comment: JS stop working usually means you've got JS errors stopping the action. I suspect hide... is a problem (there's no such thing defined) as well as secbuttons (not defined). You may have defined them elsewhere, but we can't tell without a full example (of the smallest example that fails). Also, run it in Firefox or Chrome with the JS console on, and let us know if any errors pop up.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your problem is that you're redefining `showabout` and `showcontact` — your functions — to refer to HTML elements.

These two code snippets:

```
function showabout() {
    ...
}
```

and

```
showabout = document.getElementById("aboutus");
```

both set the variable `window.showabout`. The first one assigns a function to `window.showabout`, and the latter assigns an HTML element to `window.showabout`.

Because you don't use the `var` keyword to declare the variables in your functions, `showabout = document.getElementById("aboutus")` reassigns `showcontact` to refer to that element instead of the function you're defining. So then when you try to call `showcontact()` a second time, it doesn't work because `showcontact` is no longer a function.

The easy fix is actually an all-around good rule whenever you're writing JavaScript:

### Always declare your variables

There's also a second lesson here:

#### Give your variables descriptive names

Although your code will work if you just declare the `showabout` variable ahead of time, it will still be confusing to read. The function and the element it shows should have different names. Say, call the function `showAboutBox` and the box it shows `aboutBox`. This way there's no room for confusion — either by you or the language — about which thing you're referring to.